# Will an If inside An If always be read? Not nested, but put right in front of the last one

Tags: c, if-statement, nested

The second if is always executing, no matter what the values from the first one was, I´m comparing char arrays from a struct.

Tried doing all of the comparisons in one If, like this:

`if(strcmp(t[j].NomePeca, t[n].NomePeca) == 0 && strcmp(t[j].nroPoltrona, t[n].nroPoltrona) == 0 && strcmp(t[j].hora, t[n].hora) == 0 && strcmp(t[j].data,t[n].data) == 0) { ... }`

Same thing.

```c
struct TabelaIngresso {
    char NomePeca[30];
    char data[10];
    char hora[5];
    int aPagar;
    char nroPoltrona[3];
};

// ............................

if (strcmp(t[j].NomePeca, t[n].NomePeca) == 0 && strcmp(t[j].nroPoltrona, t[n].nroPoltrona) == 0) {
    if((strcmp(t[j].hora,t[n].hora) == 0) && (strcmp(t[j].data,t[n].data) == 0)) {
        anulado = 1;
        printf("\nCompra anulada pois a poltrona nao esta disponivel!\n");
        strcpy (t[j].NomePeca, "Anulado");
        strcpy (t[j].data, "Anulado");
        strcpy (t[j].hora, "Anulado");
        t[j].nroPoltrona[3] = '0';
        t[j].aPagar = 0;
    }
}
```

This If should only be executed if all of the strings are the same.

Comment: Are you handling the cases where the strings are empty (`"\0"`)?

Comment: No @DavidRTribble ! If they got to this point, the strings contain data already..

Comment: @Willian Cesar Show a minimal complete program and input data that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there you go...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without more context we cannot tell what is not working. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) containing the data used in your example.

Comment: solved by adding a flag to each If, since everytime i compared by using those methods, a short-circuit behavior was executed, so none of the following statements were read, thanks @Ivan Velichko

Comment: regarding: `strcpy (t[j].hora, "Anulado");` and `t[j].nroPoltrona[3] = '0';`  Both of these statements result in undefined behavior.  1) the char array: `Anulado` (8 characters) will not fit into the array: `hora[5]`  2) the array: nroPoltrona[]  is 3 characters, (and array offsets always start with 0) so this is writing past the end of the array.  I.E.  Two run time problems in the posted code.  Suggest fixing such problems before worrying about if an `if()` statement is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be asking about behavior called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It is the default behavior of the majority of the commonly used programming languages. The idea is that in a boolean expression the next argument is executed or evaluated only if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression. Have a look at the example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
    return false;
}

function bar() {
    console.log('bar');
    return true;
}

if (foo() && bar()) {
    console.log('bar() will not ever be called');
} else {
    console.log('calling foo() is enough');
}
```

The code above is equivalent to:

```
const bool =  && bar();
if (foo()) {
    if (bar()) {
        console.log('bar() will not ever be called');
    }
} else if (!bar()) {
    console.log('calling foo() is enough');
}
```

But it's much easier to read the code from the first snippet.